# JPA in ManyToOne relationship only one row is getting foreign key value and other row is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

In springBoot ManyToOne relationship multiple rows is not getting fee_id foreign key instead getting null value.

```
package com.cts.BillManagement.Entities;

import java.util.Date;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="billMaster")
public class BillMaster {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="billId")
    private int billId;
    @Column(name="rideId")
    private int rideId;
    @Column(name="noOfkm")
    private int noOfkm;
    @Column(name="totalbill")
    private int totalbill;
    @Column(name="noOfOccupants")
    private int noOfOccupants;
    @Column(name="date")
    private Date date;
    
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="feeId")
    private Fees fee;
    
    @Column(name="costPerOccupant")
    private int costPerOccupant;
    
    public BillMaster(int billId, int rideId, int noOfkm, int totalbill, int noOfOccupants, Fees fee,
            int costPerOccupant) {
        super();
        this.billId = billId;
        this.rideId = rideId;
        this.noOfkm = noOfkm;
        this.totalbill = totalbill;
        this.noOfOccupants = noOfOccupants;
        this.fee = fee;
        this.costPerOccupant = costPerOccupant;
    }       

}
```

BillMaster Entity

```
package com.cts.BillManagement.Entities;


import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;

@Transactional
@Entity
@Table(name="fees")
public class Fees {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="feeId")
    private int feeId;
    @Column(name="carType")
    private String carType;
    @Column(name="carName")
    private String carName;
    @Column(name="fuelType")
    private String fuelType;
    @Column(name="averageInKm")
    private int averageInKm;
    @Column(name="costOfFuel")
    private int costOfFuel;
    @Column(name="wearTearCost")
    private int wearTearCost;
    @Column(name="drivercharges")
    private int drivercharges;
    @Column(name="carPoolCommision")
    private int carPoolCommision;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "fee")
    private List<BillMaster> billMaster;
    
    
    

    public Fees(int feeId, String carType, String carName, String fuelType, int averageInKm, int costOfFuel,
            int wearTearCost, int drivercharges, int carPoolCommision) {
        super();
        this.feeId = feeId;
        this.carType = carType;
        this.carName = carName;
        this.fuelType = fuelType;
        this.averageInKm = averageInKm;
        this.costOfFuel = costOfFuel;
        this.wearTearCost = wearTearCost;
        this.drivercharges = drivercharges;
        this.carPoolCommision = carPoolCommision;
    }

}
```

In this [Bill Master table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZa0J.png)
and both fee_id foreign key and billId primary key is getting same value.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I am trying to form ManyToOne relationship in my tables properly.

Comment: Post you service call that you implemented to fetch bill master.

Answer (score 0):

In the Fees class ( the parent ), you will need two  methods (e.g. addBillMaster and removeBillMaster) which are used to synchronize both sides of the bidirectional association.

```
public void addBillMaster(BillMaster billMaster) {
    billMasters.add(billMaster);
    billMaster.setFees(this);
}

public void removeBillMaster(BillMaster billMaster) {
    billMasters.remove(billMaster);
    billMaster.setFees(null);
}
```

> ```
> @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "fee")
> private List<BillMaster> billMaster;
> ```

I would improve the above line with this:

```
@OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "fee",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<BillMaster> billMasters = new ArrayList<>();
```

> ```
>    @ManyToOne
>    @JoinColumn(name="feeId")
>    private Fees fee;
> ```

And this I would replace with:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Fees fee;
```

Later when you need to persist this:

```
Fees fee = new Fees(...);

fee.addBillMaster(
  new BillMaster(...)
);

entityManager.persist(fee);
```

If you want to go into more details make sure to read Vlads blogpost: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/